# Bootstrap breaks grid when too large text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, line-breaks

I am working with `bootstrap` and have several items to show which I will show depending on the device that the visitor is using.
Basically I have a title, image and text, I find that when the text is longer than the others the grid breaks and one of the items starts in a new line.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
        <h2 class="text-center">See when invoices are opened</h2>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="invoice-.jpg"/>
        <p>See exactly when your invoices are sent viewed and paid. Easily add late payment fees to encourage your clients to pay on time.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
        <h2 class="text-center">Process discounts and refunds</h2>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="discounts-and-refunds.jpg"/>
        <p>Add discounts to your invoices so your customers know they're getting a great deal. Process refunds and return with ease.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
        <h2 class="text-center">Add sales taxes to your invoices</h2>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="sales-taxes.jpg"/>
        <p>Do you sell in multiple states or countries? Create as many sales tax rates as you want, and will automatically add them to your invoices based on your customers' locations.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-offset-4 col-xl-4">
        <h2 class="text-center">Decide how and when to get paid</h2>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="methods-and-terms.jpg"/>
        <p>Select custom payment terms for each client, such as Net 30 for Bob and Net 15 for Pam. Lets you choose different payment methods for each client, such as credit cards for Pam and checks for Bob.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to keep the height of each div (item) equal so it doesn't break? Or is there another fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses 12 columns in a row. It looks like you have 24.

Examples:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6>
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how all the numbers in the row add up to 12.

Comment: Yeah I know that, sorry if I didn't mention it; I have 8 items, so I just do col-md-6 to have 2 per row, and if it is bigger I will have 3 items (xl-4) per row; also notice that the XL it is a patch for bootstrap twitter.